# How to create input field dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create input field dynamically.

Input field can be consider as three dimensional matrix mat[m][n][2].

to add one more 2d matrix, there is button at the bottom and to create more rows in each matrix there is one button at the end of each matrix.

This is what I have tried. (Ignore the css)

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [info,setInfo] = useState([]);
  const addNewCond = (e) => {
    let matrix = [["",""]];
    setInfo([...info,matrix]);
  }
  const addNewDetailedCond = (index) => (e) => {
    let matrix=info[index];
    matrix.push(["",""]);
    setInfo(matrix);
  }
  
  const deleteCond = (e) => {
    
  }
  
  const deleteDetailedCond = (index) => e => {}
  const handleDetailedCond = (i,j,k) => (e) => {}
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form-horizontal form-label-left">
        {
          info.map((mat,i) => (
            <>
              {
                mat.map((rows,j) => (
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <select className="form-control" value={info[i][j][0]} onChange={handleDetailedCond(i,j,0)}>
                        <option value="test">Test</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <input className="form-control" value={info[i][j][1]} onChange={handleDetailedCond(i,j,1)}/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
              {
                mat.length !== 0 ? <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={addNewDetailedCond(i)}>Add New Detailed Info</button> : null
              }
            </>
          ))
        }
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={addNewCond}>Add New Condition</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

CodePen Link -> https://codepen.io/anonymous0045/pen/ZEMGLrN

Whenever I try to add more list in each matrix it fails, What mistake I am doing during adding more rows in particular matrix? Please help.

Comment: What exactly fails..? In your `addNewDetailedCond` you're changing state directly. You're setting the `matrix` to the reference of `info[index]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make changes in the following function in order to add nested form group for one condition.

```
const addNewDetailedCond = (index) => (e) => {
  const newInfo = info.map((mat, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      return mat.concat([["", ""]]);
    }
    return mat;
  });
  console.log("new matrix => ", newInfo);
  setInfo(newInfo);
};
```

Also, you need to add keys whenever you're rendering elements through the loop. check the warnings in console, they're helpful!

Edited version: https://codepen.io/anonymous0045/pen/ZEMGLrN?editors=0010

Let me know if this works!